# I need to check whether a string matches the pattern in postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql

I need to check if a string is in the format '4.3.10'. 
For example, If compare the strings 'AS45' or '456' or '4.1' with the above pattern, I should get a error message or boolean false.

Comment: Now I want to check the given string with a genaral format '"maximum 2 digits"."maximum 2 digits"."maximum 5 digits"."maximum 3 digits"'. I tried 'similar to','like' and '~', but none of this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use 'SIMILAR  TO' operation.
IF we want to match more than one pattern at the same time use the following query.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '(*.*._|*.*|_|*.*.**|*.***.|_.**.**|_*.**.**|*_.**.*|***..__)';

Separate each pattern with an 'OR' (|) operator. 
In the above query I am comparing 9 different patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Postgres `SIMILAR TO` statement for pattern matching. In a query, the pattern matcher would like like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]';
```

You can change the ranges within the brackets as needed.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: It is better to use `~` operator instead of `SIMILAR TO`. `~` uses POSIX Regular Expressions while `SIMILAR TO` uses `curious cross between LIKE notation and common regular expression notation`

Comment: As a regexp you'd be looking at `column ~ '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]`'

Comment: @IhorRomanchenko's comment should be placed as answear and accepted!